# Auto-calculating Geodetic Length using Geographic Coordinate System other than WGS 1984

Tags: arcgis-pro, geometry, arcade, attribute-rules, error-002717

At [How to show geodatabase calculated area and length in meters from WGS84 FC?](https://community.esri.com/t5/geodatabase-questions/how-to-show-geodatabase-calculated-area-and-length/m-p/787462/highlight/true#M1884)  (from 2018) it was said that "a little further ahead it will be possible to use Arcade expression (in Pro, not ArcMap) to leverage the [Geometry Functions | ArcGIS for Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#areageodetic)" and at [Geometry Functions | ArcGIS Arcade | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#lengthgeodetic) it appears that this has been implemented but only for:

> geometries with a Web Mercator (wkid 3857) or a WGS 84 (wkid 4326)
> spatial reference.

I am using ArcGIS Roads and Highways with ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0 and a File Geodatabase (soon an Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server) and I wanted to set an Attribute Rule which would enable me to auto-populate a field named Length of each new feature I digitize with its geodetic length based on GCS_GDA_1994 (soon GCS_GDA_2020).  I tried using an Expression (written in Arcade) of :

```
LengthGeodetic($feature, 'meters')
```

However, this resulted in an error of:

> ERROR 002717: Invalid Arcade expression, Arcade error: Projection is
> invalid, Script line: 1

I am assuming that this is because GCS_GDA_1994 is neither Web Mercator (wkid 3857) nor WGS 84 (wkid 4326).

Have I hit a hard software limit here or is there another way that I can explore to meet my requirement?

As a workaround, after each batch of new features I capture, I'm manually running a Python Script tool written in ArcPy to do that calculation using the Calculate Geometry Attributes tool.

I have also asked the Esri Community about this as a Geodatabase Question under the same title at [Auto-calculating Geodetic Length using Geographic Coordinate System other than WGS 1984](https://community.esri.com/t5/geodatabase-questions/auto-calculating-geodetic-length-using-geographic/m-p/1199709#M7807).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Known Limit in the current version and has become the subject of Enhancement Request [ENH-000151609](https://my.esri.com/#/support/cases/03124924) to support Auto-calculating Geodetic Length using Geographic Coordinate System other than WGS 1984.